# Can Cognos retrieve data via REST?

Tags: rest, cognos

I would like to use Cognos retrieve response data of IBM Forms Experience Builder via REST api. Can/How Cognos retrieve data via REST?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cognos Mashup Service: 
[Cognos Mashup Service](http://www-142.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/cognos-mashup-service/)
It is part of the Cognos SDK, and you can use REST + SOAP in order to embed Cognos Business Intelligence content into other business applications, processes or data visualization tools. 
Documentation is part of the SDK and is not availble in public. 
However, an excellent proven practice document is availble here: 
[Get started with the IBM Cognos Mashup Service](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1001cognosmashup/index.html)

Comment: Gognos mashup service seems to be useful to get data out of cognos but not to get data in. am I mistaken?

Comment: I believe @wcandillon is correct that Cognos Mashup Service is only for retrieving data from Cognos and the question is about pulling data into Cognos. Ran Avnon do you know if Cognos can make a REST API call?

Comment: You use Cognos in order to connet data sources in order to retrieve data from there. Once you are connected to the data source, you can build reports. Once the report/s are ready you can consume them with mashup services. Cognos does not support insertion of data. Cognos is BI tool for investigate existing data.